# Compare two arrays to get count of properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two arrays that I would like to compare and provide a count of the items in the master list.

The master list might look like this:

```
{ name: 'Jon', age: 34 },
{ name: 'Steve', age: 33 },
{ name: 'Mark', age: 34 },
{ name: 'Jon', age: 35 }
```

The Filter list gets all possible names / ages from the database. Some might not have any entries. Each of these lists are getting pulled from an API individually. I will combine them into one array:

```
{ users:
    [{ username: 'Jon' },
    { userName: 'Steve' },
    { username: 'Mark' },
    { username: 'Mike' }],
  ages:
    [{age: 33},
     {age: 34},
     {age: 35},
     {age: 36}]
}
```

What I would like to do is be able to count how many of each name I have

`Jon - 2, Steve - 1, Mark - 1, Mike - 0`

`33 - 1, 34 - 2, 35 - 1`

Comment: I've started through doing an `angular.forEach` loop based on the "master" list. I'm stuck trying to figure out best way to loop through each of the properties and comparing them to the filter list

Comment: @JonHarding if you're using angular, please let users know that in your question

Comment: This isn't specific to angular at all

Comment: I know you can use js in angular, but it will be probably better to use angular function, no ?

Comment: Don't you need to filter your master list before counting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic approach. You provide the data and the field you want to count.

```js
var data = [
    { name: 'Jon',   age: 34 },
    { name: 'Steve', age: 33 },
    { name: 'Mark',  age: 34 },
    { name: 'Jon',   age: 35 }
];

function countUnique(items, property) {
    return items.reduce(function(map, item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            map[item[property]] = (map[item[property]] || 0) + 1;
        }
        return map;
    }, {});
} 


console.log(countUnique(data, 'name')); // Object {Jon: 2, Steve: 1, Mark: 1}
console.log(countUnique(data, 'age'));  // Object {33: 1, 34: 2, 35: 1}
```

---

## Filtering

If you want to filter a list of users by conditions, you can define an array of filter objects as seen below. When filtering a list of items, you usually will provide a [predicate function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_predicate) to execute on the current item in the filter call. This function returns a boolean value which determines whether or not the item meets the conditions of the function.

```js
var users = [
  { name: 'Jon',   age: 34 },
  { name: 'Steve', age: 33 },
  { name: 'Mark',  age: 34 },
  { name: 'Jon',   age: 35 }
];
var filters = [{
  name: 'users',
  predicate : function(user) {
    return [ 'Jon', 'Mark', 'Mike' ].indexOf(user.name) > -1;
  }
}, {
  name: 'ages',
  predicate : function(user) {
    return user.age >= 34 && user.age <= 36;
  }
}];

print(filterFactory(users, getFiltersByName(filters, ['users', 'ages'])));

function getFiltersByName(filters, names) {
  return filters.filter(function(filter) {
    return names.indexOf(filter.name) > -1;
  });
}
function filterFactory(items, filters) {
  return items.filter(function(item) {
    return filters.some(function(filter) {
      try { return filter.predicate.call(undefined, item); }
      catch (e) { throw new Error('predicate undefined for filter: ' + filter.name); }
    });
  });
}
function print(obj) {
  document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, '  ');
}
```

```css
body { font-family: monospace; white-space: pre }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5jkqv6k3/

```js
var data = [
  { name: 'Jon',   age: 34 },
  { name: 'Steve', age: 33 },
  { name: 'Mark',  age: 34 },
  { name: 'Jon',   age: 35 }
];

var key = function(obj) {
  // Some unique object-dependent key
  return obj.name; // Just an example
};

var dict = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (dict[key(data[i])])
    dict[key(data[i])] = dict[key(data[i])] + 1;
  else
    dict[key(data[i])] = 1;
}

console.log(dict);
```

Comment: would you do this for each property rather than combining the filter into one list?

Comment: @JonHarding yes it would be better combining into a list!. Updating my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Using angularJs (because you're using it as you said) you can do this:

```
var countNamesList = {};
var countAgesList = {};
angular.forEach(masterList, function(value, index) {
    countNamesList[masterList[index].name] =
        (!angular.isUndefined(countNamesList[masterList[index].name])) ?
        countNamesList[masterList[index].name] + 1 : 1;
    countAgesList[masterList[index].age] =
        (!angular.isUndefined(countAgesList[masterList[index].age])) ?
        countAgesList[masterList[index].age] + 1 : 1;
});
console.log(countNamesList);
console.log(countAgesList);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/4k99pwvh/)

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Polywhirl's answer is your best option on counting.

Now here's how you can filter:

```js
var master = [ 
        { name: 'Jon', age: 34 },
        { name: 'Steve', age: 33 },
        { name: 'Mark', age: 34 },
        { name: 'Jon', age: 35 }
];
var filter = { 
    users: [ 
        { username: 'Jon' },
        { username: 'Mark' },
        { username: 'Mike' }
    ], ages: [
        { age: 34 },
        { age: 35 },
        { age: 36 }
    ]
};

function filterByNameAndAge(obj) {
    return filter.users.some(function(user) {
        return user.username === obj.name;
    }) && filter.ages.some(function(age) {
        return age.age === obj.age;
    });
}

console.log(master.filter(filterByNameAndAge));
```

Currently it accepts only objects with matching name **and** age. Replace the `&&` inside `filterByNameAndAge` by `||` if it should accept objects with matching name **or** age.

Comment: unfortunately filter isn't returned as a string array